# Error: Unrecognised Selector when using class reference

Tags: ios, swift, class, icloud, nsnotificationcenter

I have a class in a swift file called `cloud` I use a reference to that `class` in my project to call two of its **methods**.  But I get the following error and the app crashes;

> NSForwarding: warning: object 0x7fc938717160 of class 'App.Cloud' does
>   not implement methodSignatureForSelector: -- trouble ahead
>
> Unrecognized selector -[App.Cloud persistentStoreWillChange]
>
> (lldb)

Does anybody know who i could resolve this and why this is occurring ?
PS: The error only appears when installing the app and launching for the first time. If I quit and relaunch it does not appear, however it does not execute the methods.

**Heres my class,**

```
class Cloud {

let moc = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).managedObjectContext

func persistentStoreWillChange (notification:NSNotification) {

    self.moc!.performBlock { () -> Void in
        if self.moc!.hasChanges {
            var error:NSError? = nil
            self.moc!.save(&error)
            if error != nil {
                println("Save error: \(error)")
            } else{
                // drop any manged object refrences
                self.moc!.reset()
            }

        }
    }
}

func persistentStoreDidChange () {
    println("Store Did Change")
}


//Refresh Data
func recieveChanges (notification:NSNotification){
    self.moc!.performBlock { () -> Void in
        self.moc!.mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification(notification)
    }
}

//View Will Appear
func addObsevers() {

NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "persistentStoreDidChange:", name: NSPersistentStoreCoordinatorStoresDidChangeNotification, object: nil)

 NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: Selector("persistentStoreWillChange:"), name:NSPersistentStoreCoordinatorStoresWillChangeNotification, object: moc!.persistentStoreCoordinator)

 NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: Selector("recieveICloudChanges:"), name:NSPersistentStoreDidImportUbiquitousContentChangesNotification, object: moc!.persistentStoreCoordinator)

}

//View Will Dissapear
func removeObservers() {

 NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self, name: NSPersistentStoreCoordinatorStoresDidChangeNotification, object: nil)
 NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self, name: NSPersistentStoreCoordinatorStoresWillChangeNotification, object: moc!.persistentStoreCoordinator)
 NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self, name: NSPersistentStoreDidImportUbiquitousContentChangesNotification, object: moc!.persistentStoreCoordinator)
}

}
```

**Class reference in View Controller:**

```
let iCloudSync = Cloud()

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {

    iCloudSync.addObsevers()

    loadData()

}

override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
    iCloudSync.removeObservers()
}
```

Comment: Not exactly sure I get mixed results when using breakpoints, but looking at the error I had missed out the following line; `Unrecognized selector -[Jottit.Cloud persistentStoreDidChange]`

Comment: Made changes to the error block quote in my question for full console output error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You changed code but you forgot to change method declaration from

```
func persistentStoreDidChange () {
    println("Store Did Change")
}
```

to

```
func persistentStoreDidChange (notification: NSNotification) {
    println("Store Did Change")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to derive `class Cloud` from NSObject when you declare it, like this:

```
class Cloud : NSObject {
```

Otherwise your selectors are invisible to Objective-C.

Comment: Cheers for that but now I get the following error `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[App.Cloud persistentStoreDidChange:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f8d7e20ab20`

Comment: Yes, but you _know_ why that is. `"persistentStoreDidChange:"` (with a colon) does not match your declaration `func persistentStoreDidChange()`. See my book if you don't know how to express the name of a function as a selector: http://www.apeth.com/swiftBook/apa.html#_selectors

Answer (score 0):

Well you do this, which says to call `persistentStoreDidChange` on `self` when the notification triggers:

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self,
  selector: "persistentStoreDidChange",
  name: NSPersistentStoreCoordinatorStoresDidChangeNotification,
  object: nil)
```

But then it looks like you don't implement `persistentStoreDidChange` within `class Cloud`.

So either remove that observer, or implement the method.

Comment: I removed the observer for `persistentStoreDidChange` but then get the error for  `persistentStoreWillChange` :/ Is it something to do with how I am using the Class reference ?

Comment: Should I be adding the functions for `persistentStoreDidChange` and  `persistentStoreWillChange` to my **view controller** for the methods `iCloudSync.addObserver ` and `iCloudSync.removeObserver`

Comment: That should be fine. Though I notice your "WillChange:" notification selector has a colon at the end, but your "DidChange" does not. Since you aren't using the argument anyway, try removing the colon and making the method just `func persistentStoreWillChange() {`.

Comment: I updated the cloud class in my question to reflect the code in my project, I still receive an error for `Unrecognized selector -[Jottit.Cloud persistentStoreWillChange]` - the full error in updated in the question as well

Comment: I have done this in another project but using the code from the class Cloud directly in the view controller. But referencing the class and calling its methods is so much cleaner, especially when reusing it throughout the project.

Answer (score 0):

Your methods have parameters so you must express this with ':' in their names. Changed code should look like this:

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: Selector("persistentStoreWillChange:"), name: NSPersistentStoreCoordinatorStoresWillChangeNotification, object: moc!.persistentStoreCoordinator)
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: Selector("recieveICloudChanges:"), name: NSPersistentStoreDidImportUbiquitousContentChangesNotification, object: moc!.persistentStoreCoordinator)
```